# Brush up on as a Tri-Part

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

Is "brush up on" technically a tri-part phrasal verb?

Comment: It's sometimes just _brush up_, as in the song _Brush Up Your Shakespeare_.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one to me. See, for example, http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/three-part-phrasal-verbs